Why is "giving nachat ruach" to Hashem not considered "giving to Him" or "Him receiving from us"
There is a theme throughout all Torah thought, that we cannot give to Hashem. He is perfect and lacking nothing; He needs nothing; He has no desire to receive; He cannot receive; we have nothing to give.
There are many angles, but they all seem to agree on one thing: God can't receive from us and it's very silly, or ignorant, or heretical to say so.
As a quick example from the Baal HaSulam's Introduction to the Zohar to get the ball rolling:

ועתה שידענו בבירור שמחשבת הבריאה שהיא בכדי להנות לנבראיו, בראה בהכרח
מידת 'רצון לקבל' ממנו ית' את כל הנועם והטוב הזה שחשב בעדם. הנה הרצון
לקבל הזה, ודאי שלא היה כלול בעצמותו ית' מטרם שבראו בנשמות, כי ממי
יקבל? הרי שברא דבר מחודש שאינו בו ית׳.
We now also know, that the Thought of Creation was to benefit those that were created. Hashem had to
creat something completely new, not found in Himself. This
"something" is the desire to receive all His goodness and delight. This desire to receive is
not found in G-d Himself, because from whom should He receive? It is created new, since the desire to
receive is not found in G-d Himself.

On the other hand, giving Hashem nachat ruach (pleasure, satisfaction) through our service seems to be just as uncontroversial. We say it every day in Shacharit, quoting Rabbi Yehuda the Tanna. In the very same works that we are told Hashem does not receive from us, we are told that we give Him nachat ruach. Same sources as above:

ועל ידי עסק המצוות מי"ג שנים ואילך, שעוסק על מנת להשפיע נחת רוח ליוצרו
And through his involvement in mitzvot beginning at thirteen, for the
purpose of giving satisfaction to His Creator


My question: what reconciliations are given to this seeming contradiction? Why is the concept(s) of "giving nachat ruach" or "Hashem getting nachat ruach" possible, if He can't receive/we can't give Him anything?
I am looking for answers from any place. I would love to hear multiple reconcilations coming from various schools of thought, even opposing schools.

Necessarily, there is some reason for creation, otherwise there would be nothing rather than something (unless you posit that it derives from the divine will—sans reason—which I have a hard time wrapping my head around).
The source you cite explains it as God's desire to bestow good onto others.
That reason, which some would term a 'need', is somehow part of the divine perfection (as in, e.g., a perfect being necessarily provides goodness to others).
As mitzvos can be seen as enabling us to fully experience that good, they in turn can be seen as providing pleasure to HaShem—not per se, but indirectly—as they allow Him to realize the purpose of creation.

Kol hakavod! +1 I really like everything you said, and strongly agree with the things you didn't source (although please do provide the most solid sources you find, if you ever find them). Nonetheless, I am not clear how this answers the question because the last paragraph needs fleshing out to remove all traces of ambiguity.

Ty. I don't really have sources for the first part, just logic (hopefully sound). As for the last paragraph, see https://mgs.alhatorah.org/Dual/Ramban/Devarim/22.6#m4e1n6 where Ramban spells it all out.

Ty. I made the same point about Hashem not being frivolous here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/108779/does-god-need-us/136415#136415. It seems logical but would be nice to have an explicit agreement because theological points are often more subtle than they seem

FYI, two of my lines of reasoning that validate the argument are a) Amalek is criticised for being frivolous in various sources b) Hashem's seal is Emet, and frivolity seems devoid of Emet.
